# How can I access to a struct variable from another package in go?

Tags: go

Assume that we have two different packages let's say A and B. I have a struct in package A as following:

```
type struct1 struct {
   X int
   Y int
}
```

In package B, I want to access the variables in struct1 which is package A. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you actually mean fields by _variables in struct1_? First of all, you need a variable of type `struct1`.

Comment: yes sure, I want to access the variable X or Y from package A to use it in package B

Comment: If `struct1` is unexported and there is nothing in its package that would provide an instance of that type to a client package (e.g. an exported variable, or constructor function) then you cannot access those fields.

Comment: ... also what you call variables are called *fields* in Go. To access a struct's field you first need an instance of that struct which, as i've already mentioned in the previous comment, needs to be exported in some way or another.

Answer (score 1):

In Go, a type can be exported if it begins with a capital letter. For example, `Struct1` is exported and accessible from outside the package, but `struct1` is not since it has not been exported. Unexported names are only available inside of that package.

You can import package A into package B and access the exported type as `A.Struct1`:

```
package B

import (
    "A"
    "fmt"
)

func CreateAndPrintStruct() {
    struct1 := A.Struct1{5, 4}
    fmt.Printf("%+v", struct1)
}
```

Comment: Also, If I want to access a specific field without initializing, how can I do this? for example: (struct1 := A.Struct1.X), Is that correct?

Comment: @HamiBU: there is no field without initializing. `Struct1` is a type, there's nothing to "access".